# Bouncy Castle PKCS7 padding

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I need help to find what is actually a padding value for this expression in Bouncy Castle java framework. Kinda not sure about the values.

```
encrypt(bytes, iv, secret, "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding")
```

Comment: Are you asking what PKCS7Padding means?

Comment: PKCS#7 padding is a super set of PKCS#5 padding. Essentially PKCS#5 is only defined for a block size of 8-bytes and PKCS#7 just extends the definition to 255-bytes. Additionally if would be very uncommon to fine an implementation of PKCS#5 that did not also support PKCS#7, in practice the two can be used interchangeably.. See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding byte used is the same as the number of padding bytes. Thus, if 11 bytes of padding are needed then that padding consists of 11 copies of the byte 0x0b. Padding is always applied, so that if the number of bytes is already a multiple of 16 then 16 bytes of padding are used, the pad byte being 0x10 in that case.

This padding scheme has the nice feature that, upon decryption, you can examine the *last* byte of the padded plaintext to determine how many padding bytes there are in total.

Note that PKCS7 padding is not a java-specific standard but rather a very common padding scheme independent of language.

Comment: Yes I know, but I red that BC is not using PKCS7 padding correctly, don't know. I should program this logic in different language. In my case I got 65 bytes ten I fit 15 bytes of 0x0b to be 80 as I understand correctly?

Comment: no. If you have 65 bytes then you need 15 bytes of padding and those bytes should be 0x0f.

Answer (score 4):

If the original data is an integer multiple of N bytes, then an extra block of bytes with value N is added. This is necessary so the deciphering algorithm can determine with certainty whether the last byte of the last block is a pad byte indicating the number of padding bytes added or part of the plaintext message. Consider a plaintext message that is an integer multiple of N bytes with the last byte of plaintext being 01. With no additional information, the deciphering algorithm will not be able to determine whether the last byte is a plaintext byte or a pad byte. However, by adding N bytes each of value N after the 01 plaintext byte, the deciphering algorithm can always treat the last byte as a pad byte and strip the appropriate number of pad bytes off the end of the ciphertext; said number of bytes to be stripped based on the value of the last byte.

[image: PKCS7 padding]